# python Tkinter Display images on canvas, it always blink

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am capturing images from camera and display the images on canvas of Tkinter.
However, it appears a strange phenomenon that the canvas will blink with code as below

```
def get_image_cam() :
    global cam,cam_flag,cam_image, cam_imageTk, canvas_img
    print '[THREAD CREATE]get image camera'
    print cam_flag
    while cam_flag :
        image = cam.get_image()
        pygame.image.save(image,'capture.bmp')
        cam_image = Image.open('capture.bmp') 
        cam_imageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cam_image)
        canvas_img.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW ,image = cam_imageTk)

    print '[THREAD EXIT] get image camera'
    thread.exit_thread()
```

I have search a lot to solve this problem. Below is some code sinppets from 
http://codingmess.blogspot.com/2008/07/showing-webcam-image-in-desktop-window_08.html,
it really helps

```
def showimage(image):
    '''Loads given image and puts it into the window'''
    img = Image.open(image)
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    container.canvas.create_image(container.width/2+2, container.height/2,  image=photo)
    container.obr = photo # why is this line necessary?
```

as the author of the post saying, he did not know why this 'container.obr = photo' helps.
I did the same to my code. It changed as below:

```
def get_image_cam() :
    global cam,cam_flag,cam_image, cam_imageTk, canvas_img
    print '[THREAD CREATE]get image camera'
    print cam_flag
    while cam_flag :
        image = cam.get_image()
        pygame.image.save(image,'capture.bmp')
        cam_image = Image.open('capture.bmp') 
        cam_imageTk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(cam_image)
        canvas_img.create_image(0, 0, anchor = NW ,image = cam_imageTk)
        obr = cam_imageTk # variable 'obr' is not neccessary, you can change it to anything you want 

    print '[THREAD EXIT] get image camera'
    thread.exit_thread()
```

Is there anyone can help me explain this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PhotoImage` creates local object (inside function) which is deleted by garbage collector when you leave function (and you lose image so you get blink). It is bug in `PhotoImage`.

You have to assign this image to existing global variable or to existing object.

See `Note` in doc: [PhotoImage](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112023229/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: That sounds reasonable, while the `obr` is not a global variable or existing object ***in my function***. won't it be deleted by the garbage collector? Or if the `PhotoImage` object is assigned to an variable, it won't be deleted by garbage collector?