# display image by clicking a button tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display an image in a window with tkinter, by clicking a button.

I created this function :

```
def tabuim():
    tabu = Frame(win, width=600, height=400)
    tabu.pack()
    tabu.place(anchor='center', relx=0.8, rely=0.35)
    img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Tabu.jpg"), master=win)
    label2 = Label(tabu, image = img2, borderwidth=3, relief="solid")
    label2.pack()
```

with this button :

```
button2 = Button(win, text = 'Tabu Route Solution', command = tabuim)
button2.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.5)
```

But it partially works. It only show a border without my image...

Thanks for you help

Comment: look here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307718/python-tkinter-display-images-on-canvas-it-always-blink>

Comment: @VoidAlpha Please provide your full source code

Answer (score 0):

The following example displays a background image in a frame:

```
Import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
```

Create a photoimage object of the image in the path

```
image1 = Image.open("<path/image_name>")
test = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image1)

label1 = tkinter.Label(image=test)
label1.image = test
```

Position image

```
label1.place(x=<x_coordinate>, y=<y_coordinate>)
root.mainloop()
```

This an example you can do as instead of resizing before loading the page you could resize after the image is loaded.